# Basement Bathroom Rough In

Tags: basement

My basement shower rough-in cover is broken.

Can anyone tell me what's this cover called? Where can I purchase it? And how to replace it?

[image]

-RG

Comment: **What have you done?** Can you demonstrate that your efforts have not yielded any results and that is why you have come to us? Have you read the label on it? Have you used the internet to search for the information listed on the label? Have you clicked on any links provided by your internet search engine to learn more about the product that is on the label? Here is an example search (*i can not read the label, the photo is blurry*) https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=oatey+rough+in+box+cover&ia=web

Comment: I am assuming it is this product. 
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-11-1-2-in-x-11-1-2-in-Plastic-Bathtub-Drain-Installation-Box-34080/100343764
But I am not sure how to replace it. Searched on youtube for videos but couldn't find any.